Установил библиотеку telebot но pycharm не видит ее
Проверил все папки, делал по гайду  установил PyCharm после этого установил python, зашел в PyCharm через терминал установил библиотеку с помощью

pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

теперь пытаюсь вызвать ее и она просто не хочет видеть ее, пишешь import telebot и Pycharm пишет нету такого модуля, я не знаю что делать писал команду повторно, переустанавливал через uninstall, вручную удалил и опять скачал модуль, переустановил python. Знаю только основы python и не работал в pycharm что делать?

Проверьте работу Вашей программы в IDLE или прямо в режиме запуска .py. Если отработает, значит проблема действительно в pycharm.
